# javascript, how to set a var to a certain value then change it randomly

Tags: javascript

i have this script:

```
var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
if (randNum == 0){
alert ('0');
} else {
alert ('1');
}
```

and every time it runs i get a random value of 1 or 0

what i want is to always start the `randNum` var as being `0`

any  ideas?

thanks

Comment: that function returns 0 and 1 at a ratio of 1:2.  Is this a desired result?

Comment: Please describe better the desired outcome.  You have two answers so far that do not do what you want and the ONLY reason for that is that you have NOT been clear with what you want.  Random is random, yet you say you want a value of 0.  That plain doesn't make sense.  Please describe in more words (in your question using the edit button) what you actually want.

Comment: Your code `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);` generates a random integer of 0, 1 or 2 in equal probability.  That's what you've designed it to do.  Your `if (randNum == 0)` logic generates an alert of '0' or '1' depending upon the value of the previous random number and gives `alert('1')` 2/3 of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var randNum = null;
function getRand() {
    if (randNum == null){
        return randNum = 0;
    }
    return randNum = Math.round(Math.random());
}
```

now *that* will do it

http://jsfiddle.net/zYrS8/

or even more compact and unreadable:

```
var randNum = null;
function getRand() {
    return randNum = (randNum == null?0:Math.round(Math.random()));
}
```

Comment: @Drew awesome! I think I'll be adding that to my js arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't understand your but give this a shot:

```
var randNum = 0;
function GetRandom()
{
  if (randNum == 0){
  alert ('0');
  } else {
  alert ('1');
  }
  randNum  = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
}
GetRandom();
GetRandom();
GetRandom();
```

Comment: I ran it here and it appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dnxak/ What is it doing wrong?

Comment: every time i run it i get only 0's

Comment: It's random, so only 0's is possible, no matter how improbable...maybe you're just (un)lucky? (It works for me.) By the way, a "random" number that always starts with 0 is (obviously) _not_ random - what are you trying to do?